# HTML <input> target link

Tags: html, css

I have a button on my screen using the code 
`<input type="submit" value="Log In" class="LogInButton">` and I want when I click the button to take me to another page.

I have tried `<input href="home.html" type="submit" value="Log In" class="LogInButton">` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this part of a login form? Or just a button that takes you to a new page?

Comment: Simple use :
<button></button>

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like a case for `<a class="LogInButton" href="home.html">Log In</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `onclick` event and use `location.href` to change the URL

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" class="LogInButton" onclick="location.href='home.html'">
```

Comment: inlined javascript is evil.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an `action` property to your `form` tag.

i.e.  `<form action="home.html" ...>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered replacing you `<button>` by an `<anchor>` ?

```
<a href="home.html" class="LogInButton">Log In</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use button:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='http://yoursite.com'">Click ME</button>
```